# How to change the transmitting frequency of a FS1000A module?

Tags: rf, oscillator, 433mhz

I have tried swapping the 433 MHz crystal on a FS1000A module for an 868 MHz one, since this is the frequency my garage operates at. Now the modified module does not work reliably. I did get it to oscillate properly some of the time, and it did manage to open my garage a few times, so I know my concept works. (I'm doing this because I can't find any 868 MHz module.)

Question : How can we adapt the FS1000A module to a new cristal oscillator, and effectively change its transmitting frequency ?

The only component that seems to vary between FS1000A modules is the secondary coil, it is either the small solenoïde coil or the only SMD coil depending on the model. The goal is to adapt this component to the new desired frequency.

*Top of the board:*
[image: Top of the board]

*Bottom with measurements (the smd coil is 10uH, my bad):*
[image: Bottom with measurements]

Comment: Well you're doubling the frequency from 433 to 868, so the antenna will probably need to be modified to be the correct one. Depends on what the other components are, but you'll want to match various things to the new frequency, including RCL filters. Where's the schematic? Where's the layout? Where's the datasheet?

Answer (score 3):

That module uses a SAW resonator, not a standard crystal, so hopefully that's what you replaced it with. The RF transistor should be a [2SC3357](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/286/ne85634-243330.pdf) which has an \$f_T\$ of 6.5 GHz, so it *should* work at 868 MHz.

There should be a couple of coils on the other side of the board, one is 8 turns and appears to be an RF choke on the Vcc line. The other is 3 turns and is in the collector circuit of the oscillator. That one will probably be frequency dependent and you may need to reduce it's inductance. You can try replacing it (I'd save the original coil just in case you need it again) with a smaller coil to try to get about half the inductance, try two turns and spread them apart a little. Alternatively you could try spreading the turns on the original coil, you might not be able to get it optimal but it may help increase the signal enough to be reliable.

Also, use an antenna about half the size of the original and see if that helps.

Comment: This is a great answer thank you ! I do have a saw oscillator and have also used a 8.6cm antenna (1/4 of a wave length) The transistor is capable of handling the frequency since it has worked a few times. I have the version with a SMD secondary coil though, I measured it at 10uH, maybe i could try to replace it with solenoid inductor of my own making?

Comment: @Jbrimbelibap Can you add a photo of it to the question? Both sides of the board would be helpful, it might have a different schematic than the ones I've found online.

Comment: I've added both sides along with the measurements I made of the smd components. I thought that the capacitors had very low values but the circuit worked with values ranging from 2pF to 30pF with my own capacitors (hence why the smd ones are soldered this way, my doing )

Comment: @Jbrimbelibap Trying to match the schematics to the board, will update when I figure it out.